# LockAquisition Exceptions in JpaPagingItemReader using Spring Batch 3

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

I am using Spring Batch 3 with Spring Boot and implemented a simple job step that has the standard JpaPagingItemReader configured as reader. I am executing each chunk in this step in parallel using an SimpleAsynTaskProcessor.

The problem is that i receive (app. once every ten thousand records) LockAquisition Exceptions:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:458)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:219)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3a5ef58b.read(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:114)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2065)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1862)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:573)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:449)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Die Transaktion (Prozess-ID 67) befand sich auf Sperre Ressourcen aufgrund eines anderen Prozesses in einer Deadlocksituation und wurde als Deadlockopfer ausgewählt. Führen Sie die Transaktion erneut aus.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SQLDiagnostic.addDiagnostic(SQLDiagnostic.java:372)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.tdsErrorToken(TdsCore.java:2988)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.nextToken(TdsCore.java:2421)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.TdsCore.getNextRow(TdsCore.java:809)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.processOutput(MSCursorResultSet.java:956)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.cursorCreate(MSCursorResultSet.java:541)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.MSCursorResultSet.<init>(MSCursorResultSet.java:154)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsStatement.executeSQLQuery(JtdsStatement.java:452)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.executeQuery(JtdsPreparedStatement.java:1029)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:80)
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

The definition of my step and item reader is as follows:

```
/* when job parameter importType = FULL_IMPORT*/
@Bean(name="importIFAPFullStep")
public Step importIFAPFullStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
        @Qualifier("importIFAPFullReader") ItemReader<Product> reader, 
        @Qualifier("importIFAPWriter") ItemWriter<Product> writer,
        @Qualifier("importIFAPProcessor") ItemProcessor<Product, Product> processor) {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("importIFAPFullStep")
            .<Product, Product> chunk(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("importIFAPFullStep.chunk.size")))
            .faultTolerant()
            .retryPolicy(new NeverRetryPolicy()) //cannot retry due to multi-threaded nature
            .skipLimit(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("importIFAPFullStep.skip.limit")))
            .skip(RuntimeException.class)
            .listener(new ItemSkipListener())
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .taskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("iifs")) //new ManagedExecutorService())
            .throttleLimit(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("importIFAPFullStep.throttle.limit")))
            .build();
}

/* Reader*/
@Bean(name="importIFAPFullReader", destroyMethod="")
@StepScope
public JpaPagingItemReader<Product> importIFAPFullReader() {
    JpaPagingItemReader<Product> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<Product>();

    reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emFactoryBean.getObject());
    reader.setTransacted(false);
    reader.setPageSize(Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty("importIFAPFullReader.page.size")));
    reader.setSaveState(false); //job not restartable due to multithreaded nature
    reader.setQueryString("select new com.docmorris.pib.ifap.model.Product(p.id, p.pzn, p.clientId, p.version) from Product p order by p.pzn desc");

    return reader;
}
```

I am using sqlserver 2012 as database implementation. I was assuming that these exceptions would not occur since the JpaPagingItemReader is thead-safe and i am using it out of the box.

I tried with several other TaskExecutor implementations (and tried many other things) but nothing seems to work.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Is this something sqlserver related?

I've seen this warning at startup and are wandering if this is related: 
    **o.s.b.a.batch.BasicBatchConfigurer       : JPA does not support custom isolation levels, so locks may not be taken when launching Jobs**

I checked the source code and it seems that spring boot will always set the isolalation  level to ISOLATION_DEFAULT. But it could be that this is only isolation level for job repo, i am not sure :)

Many thx for any feedback!

Regards,

Kim